# How do I get the Entire Row back from Parse Cloud based on a condition

Tags: parse-platform, cloud

I have a datatable in Parse called Users, which users email, Id, age and etc. etc. Now I want to get the whole row back from Parse based on the email I have provided. So kind of Key, Value pair for Row and Column, so I can parse the result and display it

Comment: Which platform/SDK are you using?

Comment: Can you post the code that doesn't work?